# NoSuchMethodError while generating JasperReport's report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classcastexception

I'm generating PDF report using JasperReports library. I this report I have a QRCode which makes problem. I had to add many libraries:

jasperreports, itext, itext-pdfa, itext-pdf, commons-beanutils, commons-collections, commons-digester, commons-logging, groovy-all, barbecue, barcode, barcode4j, batik-anim, batik-bridge, core, w3c.css.sac, w3c,xmlgraphics-commons, batik-all

I receive an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SVGOMDocument cannot be cast to org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMDocument
at org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext.setDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.AbstractSvgDataToGraphics2DRenderer.ensureSvg(AbstractSvgDataToGraphics2DRenderer.java:166)
at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.AbstractSvgDataToGraphics2DRenderer.getDimension(AbstractSvgDataToGraphics2DRenderer.java:111)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.processGraphics2D(JRPdfExporter.java:1793)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.process(JRPdfExporter.java:1582)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.access$300(JRPdfExporter.java:1535)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1475)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1093)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:1056)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:920)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:537)
at reports.JasperReport.generatePdf(JasperReport.java:178)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You mis two different classes. `anim.dom` is not equals `dom.svg`

Comment: @pulpet112 What is a full stacktrace?

Comment: @Jens I added full stacktrace

Comment: @pulpet112 Could you post the expression for image (the part of *jrxml* file)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is your own code (you wrote it), it is just because of you have imported the wrong SVGOMDocument class (which belongs to different Java package).
You should be able to figured it out quickly with decent Java IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans).

Also, as much as possible try to avoid implicit imports such as:

```
import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.*;
import org.apache.batik.anim.dom.*;
```

That might reduce your code stability, e.g. lines added above might alter your reference of existing working code.
Use explicit imports (import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMDocument).

Find out what's the return type of the method you invoke, and import from the correct Java package. In Eclipse IDE, you can just remove the import that contains the package/class above, and choose Source > Organize Imports (Ctrl-Shift-O).

If you have both classes in single source code file, you might need to use full class name for one of the classes, e.g.:

```
org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMDocument document = SomeLibrary.getSomething();
```

Comment: I'm writting my own code but I don't use this classes directly. In my code, I use JRPdfExporter to export my report to pdf. And that's it - this classes are called by some others Jasper libraries